# Splitting Row into Multiple Rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'state':['FL', 'FL', 'FL'],
        'territory':[1, 2, 3],
        'proportion':['A-0.7/B-0.3', 'A-0.7/B-0.3', 'A-0.7/B-0.3'],
        'value':[10, 10, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
  state  territory   proportion  value
0    FL          1  A-0.7/B-0.3     10
1    FL          2  A-0.7/B-0.3     10
2    FL          3  A-0.7/B-0.3     10
```

For each row, I want to split the 'value' into two rows based on the 'proportion'

```
data = {'state':['FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL'], 
        'territory':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'proportion':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'value':[7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3,]}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
  state  territory proportion  value
0    FL          1          A      7
1    FL          1          B      3
2    FL          2          A      7
3    FL          2          B      3
4    FL          3          A      7
5    FL          3          B      3
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) proportion on `/`, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to create the new rows.

Then `split` again to get the letter and number, assign the letter, convert the number to float and multiply to the original value:

```
df2 = (
 df.assign(proportion=df['proportion'].str.split('/'))
   .explode('proportion')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
d = df2['proportion'].str.split('-', expand=True)

df2['proportion'] = d[0]
df2['value'] *= d[1].astype(float)
```

output:

```
  state  territory proportion  value
0    FL          1          A    7.0
1    FL          1          B    3.0
2    FL          2          A    7.0
3    FL          2          B    3.0
4    FL          3          A    7.0
5    FL          3          B    3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We do `split` 2 times , one follow with `explode` to add additional rows another need to adding the additional columns

```
out = df.explode('proportion').reset_index(drop=True)
out = out.join(out.pop('proportion').str.split('-',expand=True).rename(columns = {0:'proportion',1:'values'}))
out
Out[217]: 
  state  territory  value proportion values
0    FL          1     10          A    0.7
1    FL          1     10          B    0.3
2    FL          2     10          A    0.7
3    FL          2     10          B    0.3
4    FL          3     10          A    0.7
5    FL          3     10          B    0.3
```